# adding kml to google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am trying to overlay the KML file over google maps and want to know where I can host the kml file which I will then be able to add to the google maps. I tried using google drive and dropbox but they do not allow the file to be read from these sites.

Can somebody tell me where I can host it?

**UPDATE**

According to this [google-groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/4e95f243b2c3a85e/b9582231c11d8bd7?pli=1), I cannot overlay a KML file from my local system.

Comment: Would [Google Fusion tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/) work for you?

Comment: Ok my Map is already on Google Fusion, means I created my map using google fusion now I wish to overlay KML over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered, you cannot host the KML file on your local system. The file is fetched by Google Maps via http, so you must host it on a system that will respond to http requests *from Google Maps*. You could create an account at [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) if you want to stay in the Google ecosystem. If you're developing a web app, just host it on your web server. This is pretty much explained in the link you provided above.

A number of approaches are explained in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235/display-a-local-file-in-google-maps), which is a nearly exact duplicate.