# How upload KML from your local disk using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api

I am trying to get load my KML from my local disk with given below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.321675,-75.172631),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('C:/Users/Ashutosh_k/Downloads/newyork.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

Problem : When my google map is displaying its not showing up the elements of KML .

Comment: Fusion Tables Supports KML - https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to add local .kml files. The file needs to be stored at a location where the remote API is able to access it.

You have several choices as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514785/loading-a-local-kml-file-using-google-maps):

1. Parse the kml file yourself. There are helpful libraries for that.
2. Upload the kml file via Dropbox or Google Docs (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235/display-a-local-file-in-google-maps))

Comment: Actually i have some data which i cannot put on cloud .I am struggling since last couple of days . is there any way i keep my data in house and use google map and KML overlay as well my deadline donot permits me to explore other ways .

Comment: you can parse the kml yourself. you can use the read method from the OpenLayers KML format to get a list of features (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html)

Then you might be able to draw those features onto your map. I have never tried this, but it seems this would be your way to go then

This question is maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16629/how-to-add-kml-data-but-from-variable-not-from-url

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Martin's point that you cannot just load KML file from your local drive...

However, you can always create a google site by using your google account, and then use that site to host your kml file.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml) is a very useful/detailed documentation shows you how to do it step by step.

Hope it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Google Fusion Tables for this?
Simply create a new fusion table, upload the KML, when prompted, and use a Fusion Tables Layer to display it on a Google map!
You can find details on how to use a Fusion Tables Layer in the API doc here: [Fusion Tables Layer doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

Below, you can find a sample from the documentation linked above:

> var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
>
> map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
>
> center: chicago,
>
> zoom: 12,
>
> mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
>   });
>
> var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
>
> query: {
>
> select: 'Geocodable address',
>
> from: '1mZ53Z70NsChnBMm-qEYmSDOvLXgrreLTkQUvvg'
>     }
>
> });
>
> layer.setMap(map);